# Textarea validation with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, textarea

I wish to have input of only letters into a text area in form
It works well with the input fields, can't validate the textarea is it possible with jquery validate ? or what is another alternative 
2) will this block malicious code input (such as xss.js)

```
      <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="messageForm">
  <p>name of sender: 
   <input class="input" name="sender" id="sender" value="" size="13"
     maxlength="13" dir="ltr" autocomplete="on" type="text" height="20" minlength="3" required><br>
   <p>name of receiver: 
      <input class="input" name="receiver" id="receiver" value="" size="13"
     maxlength="13" dir="ltr" autocomplete="on" type="text" height="20" minlength="3" required><br>
   <p>Message: <br>
     <textarea name="message" id="message"  type="text" value="" rows="5" cols="30" dir="ltr" required></textarea><br>
   <input value="Submit" name="button" alt="submit" onsubmit="" border="0" type="submit" align="absmiddle"></p>

 </form>
<script>
    $("#messageForm").validate();
</script>
```

javascript

```
$().ready(function () {

    $("#submit").validate({
    rules: {
        sender: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
          lettersonly: true
        },
        receiver: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            lettersonly: true
        },
        message: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 5,
          maxlength: 30,
          lettersonly: true
        },
      },
     messages: {
                sender: {required:"Please enter your name"},
                receiver:{required: "Please enter receiver name up to 3 characters"},
                message: {required: "Enter your message 3-20 characters"},
          },
 });
```

});

when it runs on chrome gives an error on last part: *Unexpected identifier*

Comment: You should use `$(function() {` or `$(document).ready(function() {` as `$().ready(function () {` was deprecated a long time ago, and was never really good practice to begin with.

Comment: When I used $(document).ready(function() {   I can't get it to apply over firefox  - how so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `.validate()` twice...

Here...

```
<script>
    $("#messageForm").validate();
</script>
```

And here...

```
$().ready(function () {
    $("#submit").validate({...
```

The `.validate()` method is only used to initialize the plugin on your `form` and cannot be called twice.  All subsequent calls are always ignored.

However, in your case, it's ignored because you've attached the second instance of `.validate()` to `$("#submit")`, where your form's `id` is not `submit` and your `form` does not even have an `id`.  You can only attach the `.validate()` method to the `form` you want validated, which is `name="messageForm"`.

You simply need this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("[name='messageForm']").validate({
        rules: {
            sender: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                lettersonly: true
                ...
```

As already stated in comments, `$().ready(function () {...` is no longer recommended.  Use `$(document).ready(function () {...` instead.

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/unapufhp/](http://jsfiddle.net/unapufhp/)**

Comment: Great! for explaining I checked and understood I called the validation twice. and missed the ID on the form it seems to work with name as well.
althoug when I copied your code and run it on php file it didn't work

Comment: Ok It seems to run smooth, validation runs on textarea as in input